# i want to make my shoppingcart local so every time i refresh the page my stuff still needs to be in there but i just dont find the right way to do it

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code but I don't know where to start to add `localstorage`. 
I am really trying every website for help because I just can't find it.

```
var _currentArr;
var _ItemsInCart = [];
var _totalPayment = 0;
function getArticle(item, addDetails) {
  var article = document.createElement("article");
  var h3 = document.createElement("H3");
  h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.title));

  article.appendChild(h3);

  var figure = document.createElement("FIGURE");
  var img = document.createElement('img'); 
  img.src =  'images/'+item.img;
  var figcaption = document.createElement('figcaption');
  figcaption.textContent = 'Meal by: '+item.cook;
  figure.appendChild(img);
  figure.appendChild(figcaption);

  article.appendChild(figure);

  // if need details
  if (addDetails) {
    var dl = document.createElement("dl");
    var dt1 = document.createElement("dt");
    var dd1 = document.createElement("dd");
    dt1.textContent = 'calories:';
    dd1.textContent = item.calories;
    dl.appendChild(dt1);
    dl.appendChild(dd1);
    var dt2 = document.createElement("dt");
    var dd2 = document.createElement("dd");
    dt2.textContent = 'servings:';
    dd2.textContent = item.servings;
    dl.appendChild(dt2);
    dl.appendChild(dd2);
    var dt3 = document.createElement("dt");
    var dd3 = document.createElement("dd");
    dt3.textContent = 'days to book in advance:';
    dd3.textContent = item.book;
    dl.appendChild(dt3);
    dl.appendChild(dd3);
    var dt4 = document.createElement("dt");
    var dd4 = document.createElement("dd");
    dt4.textContent = 'type:';
    dd4.textContent = item.type;
    dl.appendChild(dt4);
    dl.appendChild(dd4);
    article.appendChild(dl);
  }

  // info div
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.setAttribute("class", "info");
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  p.textContent = '€'+item.price+'/pp';
  var a = document.createElement("A");
  a.setAttribute("href", '#');
  a.textContent = 'order';
  a.setAttribute("id", item.id);
  if (addDetails) {
    a.setAttribute("data-item", JSON.stringify(item));
    a.className = "order placeOrderInCart";
  } else {
    a.className = "order orderBtn";
  }

  // in div
  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(a);
  article.appendChild(div);

  return article;
}

function makeTemplateFromArray(arr) {
  _currentArr = [];
  _currentArr = arr;
  var container = document.getElementById('dynamicContent');
  container.innerHTML = '';
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
      // append article
      container.appendChild(getArticle(item, false));
    });
  }
}

function makeTemplateFromItem(item) {
  if (item) {
    var container = document.getElementById('popupContentWrapper');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(getArticle(item, true));
  }
}

function showModal(id) {
  // find item by id
  if (_MEALS && id) {
    var found = _MEALS.find(function(item) { 
      if (item.id === parseInt(id)) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (found) {
      makeTemplateFromItem(found);
    }
  }
  // open modal
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
}

// sorting
function sortItems() {
  var a = _MEALS.slice(0, _MEALS.length);
  var k = event.target.value;
  makeTemplateFromArray(doSortData(k, a));
}

function doSortData(key, arr) {
  var compare = function ( a, b) {
    if ( a[key] < b[key] ){
      return -1;
    }
    if ( a[key] > b[key] ){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
  return arr.sort( compare );
}

// change direction
function changeDirection() {
  var val = event.target.value;
  var a = _currentArr.slice(0, _currentArr.length);
  if (val === 'desc') {
    makeTemplateFromArray(a.reverse());
  } else {
    makeTemplateFromArray(_MEALS);
  }
}

// search on input
function searchInArray() {
  var val = event.target.value;
  if (val && val.length > 1) {
    val = val.toLowerCase();
    var arr = _MEALS.filter(function (item) {
      if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(val)) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    makeTemplateFromArray(arr);
  } else {
    makeTemplateFromArray(_MEALS);
  }
}

// prepare options
function prepareOptions(obj) {
  var select = document.getElementById('sortby');
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = key;
    opt.innerHTML = key;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  });
}

// add item in cart
function addItemInCart(item) {
  _ItemsInCart.push(item);
  var elem = document.getElementById('cartCounter');
  elem.innerHTML = _ItemsInCart.length;
}

// show cart
function showCart() {
  // prepare template
  var container = document.getElementById('cartItems');
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var tfoot = document.createElement("tfoot");
  container.innerHTML = '';
  var thBody = '<tr><th>Meal</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
  thead.innerHTML = thBody;
  // tbody
  _totalPayment = 0;
  _ItemsInCart.forEach(function(item) {
    _totalPayment += parseInt(item.price);
    var tBodyTemp = '<tr><td>'+item.title+'</td><td>€ '+item.price+'</td></tr>';
    tbody.innerHTML += tBodyTemp;
  });

  // tfoot
  var tfootBody = '<tr><td>Total</td><td>€ '+_totalPayment+'</td></tr>';
  tfoot.innerHTML = tfootBody;

  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  table.appendChild(tfoot);
  container.appendChild(table);
  // open modal
  document.getElementById('cart').style.display = "block";
}

// proceed to checkout
function proceedToCheckout() {
  document.getElementById('cartoverview').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('personalinformation').classList.remove('hidden');
}

// validate form submit
function validatepersonalInfoForm() {
  document.getElementById('personalinformation').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('confirmation').classList.remove('hidden');

  // set values
  var val = document.querySelector('input[name="paymentmethod"]:checked').value;
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '€ '+_totalPayment;
  document.getElementById('paymentmethod').innerHTML = 'in '+val;
}

function setRandomItem() {
  var max = _MEALS.length;
  var min = 0;
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  var item = _MEALS[number];
  document.getElementById('mealofthedayimg').src = 'images/'+item.img;
}

// listen on click event for order button
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  // close modal box
  if (event.target.classList.contains("close")) {
    document.getElementById('cart').removeAttribute('style');
    document.getElementById('popup').removeAttribute('style');

    // remove classes from element
    document.getElementById('cartoverview').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('personalinformation').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('confirmation').classList.add('hidden');
  }
  // open modal box
  if (event.target.classList.contains("orderBtn")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    showModal(event.target.getAttribute("id"));
  }

  // add item in cart
  if (event.target.classList.contains("placeOrderInCart")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var item = JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute("data-item"));
    if (item) {
      addItemInCart(item);
    }
  }
});

setTimeout( function() {
  // console.log(_MEALS);
  makeTemplateFromArray(_MEALS);
  prepareOptions(_MEALS[0]);

  setRandomItem();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly. Provide a minimal example and make clear what you tried.

Comment: How is this related to `PHP`?

Comment: if you do use php as the back end then make an ajax request to save as cookies but if you must save on browser side read on javascript localstorage()

Comment: You want to use HTML Web Storage Objects in relation to  server side php. Can you please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

- After you add something into `_ItemsInCart`, set `_ItemsInCart` as **data** in localstorage.
- Before you want to get something from `_ItemsInCart`, get **data** from localstorage first and set it to `_ItemsInCart`.

`_ItemsInCart` should always sync with your **data** in localstorage.

How to use localstorage: 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

---

Advice: If possible, separate your **DOM manipulating** code with your **logic** code.